# Kinds of android data adapters in Android sdk

Tags: android

How many kinds of data adapters are there in android SDK?

I know CursorAdapter and ArrayAdapter. Are there any more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it listed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

> **Known Indirect**
>
> Subclasses ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter, CursorAdapter,
> HeaderViewListAdapter, ListAdapter, ResourceCursorAdapter,
> SimpleAdapter, SimpleCursorAdapter, SpinnerAdapter, WrapperListAdapter

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the developers documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter, CursorAdapter, HeaderViewListAdapter, ListAdapter, ResourceCursorAdapter, SimpleAdapter, SimpleCursorAdapter, SpinnerAdapter, WrapperListAdapter.